# ReactJS correct way to call an API

Tags: reactjs

I am quiet new to ReactJS. Can any one suggest me which is the correct way to make an AJAX call?
Currently i am using

```
this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
        console.log("after serverRequest");           
    }.bind(this));
```

But I saw many samples in the tutorial

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

Please suggest me which is the correct way and why?

Answer (score 2):

If your component manages AJAX requests itself, `componentDidMount` is the correct lifecycle method to do this. `componentDidMount` is called once, and only once in the lifecycle of a component, when it is inserted into the DOM. Nevertheless, you can factor out the logic into a separate method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._serverRequest();
}

_serverRequest() {
    /* your AJAX code here */
}
```

I have put an `_` in front of the method name to express its private visibility. Although there is no method visibility support in JS, a `_` is a convention to mark a method as something you should not call from the outside. For a `React` component, the only public API that should be exposed to consumers is a set of `props`.

One important thing to keep in mind: if your component is unmounted, e.g. removed from the DOM before your Ajax request returns, you will get an Error, as you will try to `setState()` on a component that's no longer there. Although there are some safety checks you can do to prevent this, it's generally a pattern that's not recommended. You should try to manage all your AJAX requests at a higher level component, that is never supposed to be removed in the application lifecycle. If you insist on having lower-level Ajax-enabled components (a smart typeahead with server-side search, for example), it's a good practice to hide them with `style={{display: 'none'}}` when they are not needed, instead of removing them form the DOM. This not only avoids such Ajax-related errors, but also any unnecessary duplicate Ajax-requests (as `componentDidMount` would be called every time the component is newly inserted into the DOM).

But, in a real-world application, it's usually better to keep all your business logic and all your server-side communication outside of your components. Use `React` purely for rendering, and use a framework or design pattern like `redux` or `flux` for managing the application state.

Comment: I am confused, why we want to use jquery for the ajax call? if react itself providing the serverRequest method to call ajax!

Comment: @ShinoyBabu: React does not, by default, provide a `serverRequest` method on `React.Component`. You don't need to use jquery - you can use plain JS, you can use a polyfill for `fetch`, you can use whatever you chose - but you do need to write your Ajax loading logic yourself.